# Which programming languages can be used to make an operating system?

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system

I was looking around bored for stuff to do, then I stumbled across a guide on making your own simple C & Assembly command line operating system.
Im just wondering, is it just major operating system that use things like C or can an operating system be created in other languages, like android with java.

Comment: Android is based on Linux.  Most of it is written in C and assembly.

Comment: It needs to be a language that compiles to machine code, not a virtual machine or an interpreter.

Comment: @Barmar Consider Forth.

Comment: @fuz Please elaborate. I thought he had an answer until I read your comment, but I do not get it.

Comment: The cpu reads op codes from a memory addressable location and executes the op codes. You could start with any language you like so long as eventually you get down to op codes that the cpu can read and execute.  Depending on what you want your operating system to do you could start at any level you want. You could even run an operating system inside another operating system.  It sounds like you want to start at a pretty low level and see how to bootstrap yourself up from there.

Comment: Android runs Java in user-space, as a process managed by its Linux kernel.  The kernel itself is not Java.  If you wrote an OS in Java, it would be an OS for the *virtual* machine managed by a JVM, not for any real hardware.  It could probably only run Java code, unless it was also an emulator for some CPU.  (e.g. like qemu-user)

Comment: Read a wonderful book called Operating System by Andrew S Tannenbaum. As for languages, you need to have knowledge on low-level programming language ( Assembly ) and a high level language ( C/C++).

Comment: @Yunnosch Forth is a threaded-code based language which is traditionally used on “Forth systems” entirely programmed in Forth, including the operating system.  There isn't really an interpreter.   Check out a tutorial called “Jonesforth” for an introduction to this idea.  It's the ultimate fusion of a high-level and a low-level language.

Comment: Any language can be used as long as it has a "free-standing" or "bare-metal" runtime implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lowest level of an operating system is the kernel, it runs on the CPU, so the languages used can't depend on virtual machines or interpreters. Compilers create machine code from the language, and generally package the output in modules with well defined formats. Those modules can be used to create libraries, applications, or an operating system kernel. You need a language that lets you specify the module contents with a fair amount of control, a language like C is fairly easy, a language like C++ makes it much harder, so is not used for the low level of an operating system.

At the lowest level, you need complete control over the output, because it has to match the hardware, not a module format, so you use assembly language for that.

Above the kernel, there's a lot of stuff that uses higher level interfaces, so doesn't need to be a specific binary module, and can use an interpreter or virtual machine. Those levels can be in Java like Android is.

The original MacOS was written in a version of Pascal. Some IBM mainframe OSes used PL/1. Those are no longer popular, but both compiled into modules like C does.